# Jquery close modal issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so i have a modal in bootstrap that has the class of show, to have it display on page load. So it has a ender button at the bottom but couldnt get it to close on click

So I now have script that closes if clicks any where on the box but really it only on that button

**JS**

```
<script> 
  $('.modal').click(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('show'); 
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  }); 
</script>
```

**Modal box classes**

```
<div class="modal show"></div>
```

**Button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block click" style="font-size: 20px;" onClick='changeClass'">ENTER</button>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: And where is the button in relation to the modal ?

Comment: inside the modal at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work that way.
You only have to `$('.modal .close').modal("hide");`

`.close` being the class for your close button.

Or you can add attribute `data-dismiss="modal"` to close button.

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Comment: Doesn't address the button problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **bootstrap** you can do this to close and show a modal:

`$('.modal').modal('toggle');`

Check out the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods.).

Also note that **bootstrap** has an out of the box close button (which you need to include inside your modal) to handle this behavior:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
```